# Convert YouTube shared link to embed Link in my project

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, youtube, embed

Actually i want to render a youtube video in my project. For that in my cms backend I have a field to take the youtube video link which has to be rendered. But my HTML has a iframe object in that place. so when only an embed link is given in the backend, it is working. but not possible with the normal youtube link. May be if i can convert the normal link (eg:https://youtu.be/X1b3C2081-Q) to embed link in html(https://www.youtube.com/embed/X1b3C2081-Q) it may solve my issue!
This is my component.ts file:

```
open(content,video) { # since video is rendering inside a modal
this.selectVideo=video.videoLink.url;
console.log(video);
console.log(video.videoLink.url);
this.videoUrl= this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.selectVideo);

this.modalService.open(content, {ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-basic-title', size: 'xl'}).result.then((result) => {
  this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
}, (reason) => {
  this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
});
```

And this is HTML (angular):

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 z-depth-1-half">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" [src]="videoUrl" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Please explain if there is any error description - not working is not enough information.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave
 Actually  when i give a normal YouTube link in my backend..my video is not playing, just the empty modal is appearing .But when i give a embed link in backend, video is playing inside the modal just fine. What i was saying that if i could write a function to convert this link to embed before rendering in the HTML. it should work right. please see my .ts file where i wrote the code for getting the video inside the modal.(my backend is apostrophe CMS-headless)

Comment: A workaround is: handle the URL as a string; get the `video_id` and in another string concatenate the `video_id`. Sample: `string embed_str = "https://youtu.be/" + video_id_str;`.